# Concatenate and pass as parameter, bash

Tags: bash, ssh, command-line

Need to remove default gateway. For example, there is an IP 192.168.4.15 with default gateway 192.168.4.14. I connect to WLAN with gw 10.0.0.1 and after that I would like do remove previous gw.

```
  IFS='.' read -ra IPARR <<< "$IP"
  Gateway="${IPARR[0]}.${IPARR[1]}.${IPARR[2]}.14"
  ssh blah@$IP '/sbin/route -v del default gw $Gateway;'
  #ssh blah@$IP '/sbin/ip route delete $Gateway dev rndis0;'
  #ssh blah@$IP '/sbin/route -n'
```

Both ways don't work. However, it is possible to remove it if I ssh into machine. My guess is that something wrong with passing $Gateway variable. Any suggestions?

Comment: You're using the wrong quotes. `''` prevent variable expansion.

Comment: @muru, or with `ssh` it will mean that the variable will get expanded on the remote host rather than locally where the `Gateway` variable has been set.

Comment: @Graeme Indeed.

Comment: Thanks guys, I have been trying to figure out what is wrong for a few hours already.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27703579/7552

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the answer is to use double quotes when ssh'ing into machine:

```
ssh blah@$IP "/sbin/route -v del default gw $Gateway;"
```

Comment: You should stop using obsolete commands, and start using *ip* instead: *ssh blah@IP "/sbin/ip route del default via $Gateway"*

Comment: @MariusMatutiae, could you explain more what is the difference between _route_ and _ip route_?